# How to summarize the main content of an article in a webpage?

Tags: java, jsoup, summarization, boilerpipe, classifier4j

I am trying to write an article summarizer for HTML pages. So far I have used [boilerpipe](https://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe) and [classifier4J](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html).

```
//url can be any url in String
public String getArticleSummaryFromUrl() {
    private Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();;
    String summary = "";
    String article = "";    
    try {
        article = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(doc.html());    
        System.out.println("Article ++++ >>" + article);
        SimpleSummariser ss = new SimpleSummariser();       
        summary = ss.summarise(article, 4);
        } catch (BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return summary;
}
```

But most of the time the code does not produce desired results, as the sentence construction is not properly done.

I am trying to implement something as neat as http://smmry.com/.

Does any one know any java library that does this for you?

Comment: Why not use the smmry API then? http://smmry.com/api

Comment: @FredericKlein I don't want to depend on external calls. The service that I am building already contains lot of processing. I don't want to make any other external calls and also don't want to depend on external APIs.